# Protractor - How to find an element inside an element when sub element is also a main element somewhere else in a page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor

```
<div class="base-view app-loaded" data-ng-class="cssClass.appState">
<div class="ng-scope" data-ng-view="">
<div class="ng-scope" data-ng-include="'partial/navigation/navigation.tpl.html'">
<div class="feedback-ball feedback-ball-show feedback-ball-big" data-ng-class="feedback.cls" data-ng-click="outside($event)" data-feedback-ball="">
<span class="close-button"></span>
<h2 class="ng-binding">Welcome to Garbo</h2>
<div class="ng-scope ng-binding" data-ng-bind-html="feedback.html" data-ng-if="feedback.html">
<p>Here you can play in style in a safe and secure environment.</p>
<p>
<a class="btn" href="/account">My Account</a>
<a class="btn" href="/deposit">Deposit</a>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to find and click /account button inside data-ng-bind-html="feedback.html", I can find data-ng-bind-html="feedback.html" but I could not find account button inside it. when I try to find account button, it gives me error that page has multiple account button so be more specific.

I tried element.().element() but it didnt work, please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`element` calls can be chained](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.element) to find elements inside other elements, so your `element().element()` solution should work.

Alternatively, you can construct an *xpath expression* to reach the link inside the appropriate `div`:

```
element(by.xpath('//div[@data-ng-bind-html = "feedback.html"]//a[@href = "/account"]'))
```

Comment: Didnt help it says - element(by.xpath('//div[@data-ng-bind-html = "feedback.html"]')).element(by.xp
th("//a[@href='/account']"))
warning: more than one element found for locator By.xpath("//a[@href='/account']
) - you may need to be more specific
warning: more than one element found for locator By.xpath("//a[@href='/account']
) - you may need to be more specific
warning: more than one element found for locator By.xpath("//a[@href='/account']
) - you may need to be more specific.... I dont get it, why it is asking for more specific.

Comment: @hny2015 okay, can I share the complete HTML source of the page? Thanks.

Comment: @hny2015 yup, for example, create a temporary `gist` on github. Thanks.

Comment: This is the HTML code please help. I am finding it way too hard to find solution to this.

Comment: @hny2015 ok, thanks for providing the HTML. I've updated the xpath, please recheck.

Comment: it worked like a charm, cool but what was the issue ? thanks a ton !!

Comment: @hny2015 it's just that the `a` tag was not a direct child of the `div` (replaced `/` with `//`). Consider accepting the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that webDriver is finding more than one element that matches. You have element for finding just one, and element.all for taking an array of elements, then you can use .get() and the index of the element, or first() or last(). You can do,

```
element(by.css('[data-ng-bind-html="feedback.html"]')
.element(by.cssContainingText('.btn', 'My account'));
```

If it doesn't work then you might have more than one, if so, you can use,

```
element(by.css('[data-ng-bind-html="feedback.html"]')
.all(by.cssContainingText('.btn', 'My account')).first();
```

But there you will have more than one button in your HTML, webDriver will get only one,
another thing, is to use the count() that gives you the length of the array of elements, and you can know how much you have.